# Xamarin - How to get ListView text from selected row and open a new Layout/Window?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I´m currently at the beginning of Android app development and definitely need some help with it^^.  I have a ListView and want to get the text from the selected item when the list is gonna be touched. (Every row is a GroupName) It should open a new Layout/Window containing another ListView with the previous focused text as the headline and some buttons.

On which methods i can take a look to get the text from the selected ListView item and to open/create a new Window/Layout?  I couldn´t find something like this.

Comment: u want to pass your listview item data to next activity??

Comment: I think yes, that´s maybe the thing i´m looking for^^